# Azure Site recovery

Tags: vmware-esxi, azure, migration, site-to-site-vpn, disaster-recovery

Planning for ASR and migrating all our servers to Azure in distant future from VMware. Issue is that we do not have any VPN capable device in the network and have read that it is necessary.

Can anyone tell if it is possible to use ASR without configuring Site to Site  VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Per Microsoft documentation, replication happens over direct internet connectivity instead of via Site-to-Site VPN.

**Can I replicate over a site-to-site VPN to Azure?**

Azure Site Recovery replicates data to an Azure storage account, over a public endpoint. Replication isn't over a site-to-site VPN. You can create a site-to-site VPN, with an Azure virtual network. This doesn't interfere with Site Recovery replication.

[Azure Site Recovery: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-faq)

[Prepare on-premises VMware servers for disaster recovery to Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-tutorial-prepare-on-premises)